# Black video window after calibrate cameras with OpenCV

Tags: python, opencv, computer-vision

I am trying to calibrate two cameras. I'm using a code (not made by me) and it can generate the stereoMap without any problem. However, when I try to open the cameras with the new "settings" that are in the stereoMao file the windows where I should see the video calibrated are black. Sometimes one of the window shows a small part of the image that is being recorded by that camera.
This is the part of the code that is not working as I expected:

```
import numpy as np
import cv2


# Camera parameters to undistort and rectify images
cv_file = cv2.FileStorage()
cv_file.open('stereoMap.xml', cv2.FileStorage_READ)

stereoMapL_x = cv_file.getNode('stereoMapL_x').mat()
stereoMapL_y = cv_file.getNode('stereoMapL_y').mat()
stereoMapR_x = cv_file.getNode('stereoMapR_x').mat()
stereoMapR_y = cv_file.getNode('stereoMapR_y').mat()

cap_right = cv2.VideoCapture(0)                    
cap_left =  cv2.VideoCapture(1)

while(cap_right.isOpened() and cap_left.isOpened()):

    _, frame_right = cap_right.read()
    _, frame_left = cap_left.read()

    # Undistort and rectify images
    frame_right = cv2.remap(frame_right, stereoMapR_x, stereoMapR_y, cv2.INTER_LANCZOS4, cv2.BORDER_CONSTANT, 0)
    frame_left = cv2.remap(frame_left, stereoMapL_x, stereoMapL_y, cv2.INTER_LANCZOS4, cv2.BORDER_CONSTANT, 0)
                     
    cv2.imshow("frame right", frame_right) 
    cv2.imshow("frame left", frame_left)

    if cv2.waitKey(1) & 0xFF == ord('q'):
        break

cap_right.release()
cap_left.release()

cv2.destroyAllWindows()
```

I have been using more than 5 images of a chessboard to calibrate the cameras and generate the stereoMap file.
Any idea to solve this problem?
Thanks,

[Edit: These are the "black windows"](https://i.stack.imgur.com/kd3Ku.png)

Comment: why do you discard the success values from the read() calls? -- please present your cameras' intrinsics.

Comment: Are the success values important here?

Comment: are they False? are those frames *ever* blank/black or not? you still need to present those intrinsics.

Comment: Success values are True for both cameras.
These are my cameras matrixes:
```[[971.79715177   0.         651.23385355]
 [  0.         974.44895859 344.84856982]
 [  0.           0.           1.        ]]``` and 
```[[1.00773906e+03 0.00000000e+00 6.48872153e+02]
 [0.00000000e+00 1.01043553e+03 3.42019875e+02]
 [0.00000000e+00 0.00000000e+00 1.00000000e+00]]```

Comment: those camera matrices look okay. what about distortion coefficients, do you use those at all? what about extrinsics? you are trying to do stereo vision here. if you can, upload the "stereoMap" data somewhere.

Comment: Distortion coefficients are ```[[-0.05285346  0.68051089 -0.00392981  0.00157481 -1.50022473]]```and ```[[ 0.22919207 -1.31415155 -0.00275432  0.00397908  2.28301473]]```. You can download the stereoMap [here](we.tl/t-nS58kbu2UV ) Edit: Sorry,  you need to add http:// to the link. I couldn't add that part.

Comment: those maps look completely broken. how did you calculate them? also, they're the fixed point kind, so MIGHT have to tell remap that they're this kind. -- please take the [tour], review [ask] and [mre]. I can't keep asking for every little piece of information. present EVERYTHING.

Comment: [This is the code that I'm using to calibrate the cameras and calculate the stereoMap](https://github.com/niconielsen32/ComputerVision/blob/master/stereoVisionCalibration/stereovision_calibration.py)
Why do you say that the maps are broken?